# How can I replace a character with an unicode image?

Tags: unicode, jasper-reports

How can I replace a **-** character in a text which comes from a data base into jasper field, with an image? The goal is as the illustration bellow:

[image: goal]

Something like: `$F{KN_Zusatzinfo_DV_Einleitungstext}.replaceAll("- ", "[\\x254]")` where the `x254` is ascii code for a red square.

But the above code writes the ascii code as is in the text and does not produce the image.

Comment: You can try to play with markup

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The correct syntax to render a unicode symbol is `\uXXXX`

For example this expression:

```
$F{listItem}.replaceAll("-", "\u2588")
```

Will **render** this

[image: Output]

Now you like the dot **to be red** so we need to apply some style, lets set `markup="html"` on `textElement` and change the replace to this

```
$F{listItem}.replaceAll("-", "<font color=\"red\">\u2588</font>")
```

**It will render:**

[image: Red dots]

> **Note:** You need to be careful with regex in `replaceAll`, I probably would us
>   `^-`, hence starts with `-` (to avoid replacing other `-` in text),
>   furthermore the normal way would be to just add a red rectangle element on
>   each row. Also take care of font-extensions if you are exporting to
>   pdf, so that your font is render correctly

Comment: I changed the markup to styled instead of HTML. HTML omitted all my new lines. But the styled worked perfectly

Comment: @Iman in html `<br/>` is newline not `\n`, I guess another replaceAll will fix it : )

Comment: Nice answer and properly explained ,+1