# How to add indentation on bullet list?

Tags: jasper-reports, indentation

I want to add some indentation to my text field. I've already added a bullet style (adding the `<li>` tag to the text) but it seems that JasperSoft Studio doesn't automatically indentate the text.

Even if setting the *"styled"* markup and adding a `<ul>` tag at the top of the paragraph like this:

```
"<ul><li> Example text 1... </li><li> Example text 2... </li></ul>"
```

JasperSoft is still not able to manage the `<ul>` tag (looking at the documentation, unfortunately, also other HTML tags..) so the result is not what I wanted.

At this point I tried to search on different forums and I found that I could create a manual *report style* and apply that to my text field (following this guide: [Indentation in generated PDF using JasperReports](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26551095/indentation-in-generated-pdf-using-jasperreports)) but niether this worked for me.

I also tried to put a manual configuration, thinking that creating a style could not be comfortable for Jaspersoft, and set to the text field a configuration like this:

[image: Border configuration]
  [image: First line indentation]

So, setting as *left padding* property the **10 px** value, all the text should get a small displacement to the right. Setting the *first line indentation* property at **-10 px** the first line of the paragraph should automatically get to the **0 px** position, based on the margin of the page. 
This should be all my indentation, and it seems that JasperSoft is understanding this because of this:

[image: JasperSoft text indentation]

Printing the page the result that I get is completely different.

[image: Here]

Does anyone know what I do forget?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This would be a quick way to make a bullet list without using attribute tag html, that you have correctly defined as not well supported by jasper-reports.

Use the unicode symbol [`\u2022`](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/2022/index.htm) to represent the bullet, with the following example text (`\n` is line break)

```
"\u2022 Some text on line 1 that gets longer to wrap\n\u2022 This is text on line 2"
```

Then you can set `leftPadding="10"` and `firstLineIndent="-10"` as described in [Indentation in generated PDF using JasperReports](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26551095/indentation-in-generated-pdf-using-jasperreports)

**Example jrxml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<jasperReport xmlns="http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/jasperreports" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/jasperreports http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/xsd/jasperreport.xsd" name="Indentation" pageWidth="595" pageHeight="842" whenNoDataType="AllSectionsNoDetail" columnWidth="555" leftMargin="20" rightMargin="20" topMargin="20" bottomMargin="20" uuid="f0ac92f3-35e5-417e-aecd-5c47be379bf8">
    <property name="com.jaspersoft.studio.data.defaultdataadapter" value="One Empty Record"/>
    <queryString>
        <![CDATA[]]>
    </queryString>
    <title>
        <band height="44" splitType="Stretch">
            <textField isStretchWithOverflow="true">
                <reportElement x="0" y="0" width="110" height="40" uuid="3563a40d-d80e-4e09-9d84-d4f1779c1895"/>
                <box topPadding="0" leftPadding="10" bottomPadding="0" rightPadding="0"/>
                <textElement markup="none">
                    <paragraph lineSpacing="Single" firstLineIndent="-10" leftIndent="0" spacingBefore="0"/>
                </textElement>
                <textFieldExpression><![CDATA["\u2022 Some text on line 1 that gets longer to wrap\n\u2022 This is text on line 2"]]></textFieldExpression>
            </textField>
        </band>
    </title>
</jasperReport>
```

**Output**

[image: result]

> Probably however if it was me I would have converted the text to a
>   [`JRDataSource`](http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/api/net/sf/jasperreports/engine/JRDataSource.html)
>   and used the `jr:list` component. For an example on how to create a datasource from a String see this  [How to convert a , separated String to a table layout?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33721701/5292302)
>    and if you instead are wondering how you can manipulate your text to insert the unicode see [How can I replace a character with an unicode image?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38753725/5292302)

**Edit adding solution preferred by me which avoids `firstLineIndent="-10"` hack**

The solution is to convert the string into a JRDatasource in this example

```
 new net.sf.jasperreports.engine.data.JRBeanCollectionDataSource(java.util.Arrays.asList($P{testText}.split("\n")))
```

and then used the `jr:list`, with `<field name="_THIS" class="java.lang.String"/>`

**Full jrxml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<jasperReport xmlns="http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/jasperreports" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/jasperreports http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/xsd/jasperreport.xsd" name="Indentation" pageWidth="595" pageHeight="842" whenNoDataType="AllSectionsNoDetail" columnWidth="555" leftMargin="20" rightMargin="20" topMargin="20" bottomMargin="20" uuid="f0ac92f3-35e5-417e-aecd-5c47be379bf8">
    <property name="com.jaspersoft.studio.data.defaultdataadapter" value="One Empty Record"/>
    <subDataset name="ListDataset" uuid="a6053d26-ad58-4808-ac51-76e62529d7de">
        <queryString>
            <![CDATA[]]>
        </queryString>
        <field name="_THIS" class="java.lang.String"/>
    </subDataset>
    <parameter name="testText" class="java.lang.String">
        <defaultValueExpression><![CDATA["Some text on line 1 that gets longer to wrap\nThis is text on line 2"]]></defaultValueExpression>
    </parameter>
    <queryString>
        <![CDATA[]]>
    </queryString>
    <title>
        <band height="34" splitType="Stretch">
            <componentElement>
                <reportElement x="0" y="0" width="170" height="20" uuid="a9d62b3a-cdad-4c44-a3e6-8e7688986380"/>
                <jr:list xmlns:jr="http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/jasperreports/components" xsi:schemaLocation="http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/jasperreports/components http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/xsd/components.xsd" printOrder="Vertical">
                    <datasetRun subDataset="ListDataset" uuid="a21cd89b-dd5a-4135-90e0-a84ef83bd9dc">
                        <dataSourceExpression><![CDATA[new net.sf.jasperreports.engine.data.JRBeanCollectionDataSource(java.util.Arrays.asList($P{testText}.split("\n")))]]></dataSourceExpression>
                    </datasetRun>
                    <jr:listContents height="20" width="170">
                        <ellipse>
                            <reportElement x="13" y="4" width="4" height="4" backcolor="#000000" uuid="c2a202b7-ca0f-4ce4-a2d8-35b314f8e1ee">
                                <property name="com.jaspersoft.studio.unit.width" value="pixel"/>
                                <property name="com.jaspersoft.studio.unit.height" value="pixel"/>
                            </reportElement>
                        </ellipse>
                        <textField isStretchWithOverflow="true">
                            <reportElement x="30" y="0" width="80" height="20" uuid="31b05be1-9d89-4928-aec8-095e15e66711"/>
                            <textElement textAlignment="Left"/>
                            <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$F{_THIS}]]></textFieldExpression>
                        </textField>
                    </jr:listContents>
                </jr:list>
            </componentElement>
        </band>
    </title>
</jasperReport>
```

The output is same as above, but we are not hacking with negative values which could create problems on certain exports.

Comment: Thank you Petter for the answer, I'll try your suggestions and I'll let you know if they solve my problem and wich is the optimal solution for me. Thank you also for the guides that you gave me, they'll definitely be interesting.

Comment: Hi @PetterFriberg Friberg, I just had a moment to try your first suggestion (unicode symbol \u2022 and leftPadding="10" and firstLineIndent="-10") but the result is still negative for me. 
This is what I tried to do: 
1. I formatted my text with your specifications, but this didn't worked (https://imgur.com/a/zIAAO).
2. I copied the XML code that you put as example, changing the text expression with my text but niether this worked.
3. I put the same values as the example, to see if it was a text formatting problem by me, but still not working. 

I hope I'm still forgetting something.

Comment: @Roberto Try exactly with my example, you can run it with an EmptyDatasource what do you get? I also tried with old iReport and it also rendering as expected in that.

Comment: @PetterFriberg I already tried with your example but niether that worked. I copied the same code that you posted on the answer, tried to delete the _spaces_ between the '\u2022' and my text, to be sure that the problem isn't the format, but nothing gained. Seems that JasperSoft doesn't get the _firstLine_ indent for my case. May it be the version of JasperSoft Studio? Mine is the 6.2.1.final.
Ps. How can I run your code with an EmptyDatasource? Just creating a new Report page, right? Sorry for the simple question but I'm new on reports.

Comment: @Roberto yes, create a new report, go to source tab copy and pass exactly my code, then switch to preview tab, select "One Empty Record" datasource and press the green arrow button, you should get exactly what I have passed in screenshot. If so you have a problem with your other code (check settings on textfield etc), if not well that would be a surprise, since screenshot is from 6.2.1 final version

Comment: *anyway since I don't really like this solution, I will edit the post and show you exactly what solution I would have used*

Comment: I've just done an example with your indications, and I was able to replicate your code, so I see the corrected indentation. At this point I tried to copy my report source code and pasted to the _source_ tab instead of your code, I went to the _preview_ tab, compiling with "One Empty Record" and the result that I get is the correct one! I can't understand why when I print this using the interface of my web application it is printed on a different way.

Comment: @Roberto, since negative firstLineIndent is kind of a hack (I'm not sure what will happen in different exports, I have added a clean jasper-report solution, see last edit

Comment: @PetterFriberg Setting the first line indentation property at -10 px, dont work, negative values you cant apply in this property

Comment: @EriksonRodriguez you can if you edit the jrxml directly, anyway there is also a solution that does not need that.

Answer (score 2):

Very simple approach if don't need text reflow:

- Set "Markup" to `none`
- Use `\u2022` to get a bullet.
- Break the text into lines manually
- Put `\u00a0\u00a0\u00a0` (non-breaking space) in front of each line which doesn't have a bullet. This fakes the indent pretty well.

Drawbacks:

- You have to break the lines manually
- Doesn't support nice spacing between paragraphs. Just can only have whole empty lines.

Comment: Very simple to short text but if if a long text, it is a hard work jejeje