# Jasperreports Indent after the first line

Tags: jasper-reports

I am producing reports with jasper 6.6.0 in PDF and docx.
The problem that I am facing is that I can not have a paragraph indention after the first line. The input text is a paragraph separated by new lines from a XML file:

```
<Literatur>Bjelland, EK; Wilkosz, P; Tanbo, TG; Eskild, A (2014). Is unilateral oophorectomy associated with age at menopause? A population study (the HUNT2 Survey). Human Reproduction 29(4): 835-41. DOI: 10.1093/humrep/deu026

Leitlinienprogramm Onkologie (AWMF, Deutsche Krebsgesellschaft, Deutsche Krebshilfe) (2012): S3-Leitlinie Diagnostik, Therapie und Nachsorge des Mammakarzinoms, Langversion 3.0, 2012, AWMF-Registernummer: 032/045OL, http://leitlinienprogramm-onkologie.de/Mammakarzinom.67.0.html (Recherchedatum: 15.10.2015). Stand: Juli 2012, gültig bis 30.06.2017.
    </Literatur>
```

I add  and put each line between

and then the following style:

```
    <style name="indent" style="Standard">
    <box leftPadding="5"/>
    <paragraph firstLineIndent="-5"/>
    </style>
```

Using in text field:

```
    <textField isStretchWithOverflow="true" isBlankWhenNull="true">
            <reportElement style="indent" positionType="Float" x="0" y="159" width="465" height="28" uuid="f7184f30-82ee-44b4-8dcb-9d3d70ac3bc8"/>
            <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$F{Literatur}]]></textFieldExpression>
        </textField>
```

as has been posted in [Indentation in generated PDF using JasperReports](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26551095/indentation-in-generated-pdf-using-jasperreports) but this mad the literatur part to vanish and not showing at all.

How can I produce export in PDF and docx just like my java export?

DOCX looks like:
[image: docx export]

PDF looks like:
[image: PDF export]

Java export which is correct:
[image: java export]

Comment: The negative indent is buggy can you create a datasource like this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47225881/how-to-add-indentation-on-bullet-list/47227580#47227580 see last section

Comment: I see. I am trying your link, but jasper can not resolve the _THIS field?

Comment: well I have no clue why, I would need to see the code, where does it not resolve it?. Anyway your solution is to stop using negative indent